# Double user on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

It seems currently I have two users on Stack Overflow, and I would like to merge them. I have access just to one of them, https://stackoverflow.com/users/1361002/jesus

But there isn't any way I can access the second one as it's a non-registered user, https://stackoverflow.com/users/677038/jesus

As you can see, they share the same avatar and my profile at Meta Stack Overflow contains some links to both Stack Overflow profiles, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/243499/jesus.

Is there a way of keeping just one profile?